# Merging 2 files with the same name in 2 different branches in git

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I currently have a file named `test1` in a branch named `branch1` created from `master` and another file also named `test1` in a branch named `branch2` also created from `master`.
What's gonna happen to the code written in both files if I merge the 2 branches in master?

Comment: Create a test branch and then try your merge and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you made changes to both files in the same place, there will be a merge conflict.

If you didn't made changes to both files in the same place, it will merge without problems(maybe a conflict at another location).

You can solve a conflict by editing the conflicting files, removing the commit markers, adding the files and committing it.

Comment: thanks for your response I might have some conflict if since I will write code starting at line 1 in both branches

Answer (score 4):

As [amer answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59532577/1256452) (correctly), you'll get a merge conflict in *one* of the two merges.  You will have to do something to handle the merge conflict.  What to do is up to you.  It's worth pointing out, though, *why* you will get *one* merge conflict, not two, and why the merge conflict happens.

Git's merging is not really about *branches*.  It's about *commits*.  Most of Git is really about commits, and `git merge` is no different here.

Let's note here what a commit is and does.  Each commit has two parts: its *data*—a saved snapshot of all of your files—and its *metadata*, or information about the commit.

- The saved snapshot is pretty straightforward: if you clone a repository and use `--no-checkout`, you have an empty work-tree (no editable or usable copies of *any* file, yet).  Then you pick some commit—any commit anywhere—and tell Git to check out that particular commit, perhaps by its raw hash ID.  Now you have a copy of all the files as of the way they looked when whoever made that commit, made that commit.

  In general, this is what `git checkout` or the new-in-Git-2.23 `git switch` command is for: you pick some commit and say *get me all the files from that commit*.  They go into your *working tree* or *work-tree* where you can see them and work on them.  You can also put other, un-Git-ified files into your work-tree, e.g., compiled files or outputs or whatever.  These files remain *untracked* (I won't go into the precise details here, but they're not in Git, they just sit there in your work-tree unless/until *you* remove them).
- The *metadata* in a commit records things like who made it—their name and email address—and when they made it.  This is the stuff that you see in `git log` output.

  There is one part of the metadata, though, that is specifically for Git itself.  Every commit has a unique hash ID, which every Git everywhere agrees on: that one hash ID is for *that* commit, and never for any other commit.  So it's easy to tell if you have some commit: you just give its hash ID to Git, and your Git either has it, in which case, it has *that* commit, or your Git doesn't have it, in which case you'll have to find some other Git hat has it.

  Anyway, every commit stores, as part of its metadata, the hash ID of its previous or *parent* commit.  Most commits just have one.  Merge commits are slightly special because they have *two* parents (or more, but most just have two).

  These parent commits—or parents, for merges—are how Git stores history.  Every snapshot is just a snapshot, but every snapshot also says: *and my previous snapshot is ______* (fill in the blank with a hash ID).  For merges, this is the *first* parent.  For regular commits, it's the only parent (and hence also the first parent).  So by going back to the first parent of each commit, Git can trace back what has happened over time.  Put up two snapshots: an old snapshot, on the left, and a new snapshot, on the right, and compare them.  [What's different?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference)  That difference tells you what happened: what changed between the old one and the new one.

Once you know this about commits, we need only add one more thing to make branches work.  **In Git, a *branch name* records the hash ID of the *latest* commit that we wish to call "part of the branch".**  That's mostly it—that's what a branch name does for us and for Git.  It records the *last* commit.  The commits themselves record the history.

So, given a series of commits, in a very small repository with just three commits and one branch name, we have, for instance:

```
A <-B <-C   <--master
```

The *last* commit is `C`.  We have the name `master` to store its actual hash ID—which is really some big ugly random-looking string of letters and digits, that we never could guess.  Commit `C` itself stores the hash ID of earlier commit `B`, so that C *points to* `B`; and commit `B` stores the hash ID of earlier commit `A`.

Commit `A` is special: it doesn't point back at all, because it was the very first commit and can't point back to an earlier commit.  That's how Git knows to *stop* going back: when it can't.

We could, given a Git repository, go in and find all commits, and see which ones are the last one(s), but having a name that finds them quickly is faster.  This also becomes important when we start having more than one branch.  Let's start with a small repository with about eight commits:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
```

Now let's add a new branch.  We'll start by having the new *name* **also** select commit `H`.  We need a way to know *which branch we're using*, so we'll attach the special name `HEAD` to one of the branch names:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, feature1 (HEAD)
```

Now we'll add a new commit, which gets some new random-looking hash ID that we will just call `I`:

```
          I   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
```

When we add a *new* commit, Git *automatically updates the branch name* to point to the new commit.  Which branch name gets updated?  The one `HEAD` is attached-to.  The others all stay in place.

Now all the commits through `H` are on *both* branches, and commit `I` is *only on `feature1`.  Let's make another commit, then make a new branch `feature2` that selects commit `H`, and start using that one:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, feature2 (HEAD)
```

Now let's add two commits to `feature2`:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
```

Now, suppose in commit `I` or `J`, we created a *new* file `test1`, that's not yet in commit `H`.  Suppose that in commit `K` or `L`, we *also* created a new file named `test1`.

#### Merging

We're now going to merge the two features into `master`, one at a time.  For no obvious reason,<sup>1</sup> we will use the `--no-ff` option:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff feature1
```

to achieve this.

When we `git checkout master`, we direct Git to:

1. extract the commit identified by the name `master`—commit `H`—to our work-tree (and to Git's *index*, which we won't get into here); and
2. set up our work-tree to match, which means *removing* the file `test1`, which is in commit `L`—there is a saved snapshot file with that name—but is not in commit `H`.

So, now we have:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1
         /
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- feature2
```

and we're ready to run `git merge --no-ff feature1`.

Git now finds *three commits*, not just two.  The three commits of interest are:

- Our current commit, `HEAD`.  That's really easy to find because `HEAD` is attached to a branch name and the branch name points to the commit, so Git finds commit `H`.
- The other commit we named.  That's really easy too: we said to merge `feature1`.  The name `feature1` identifies commit `J`.  (Just look at the drawing!)
- The *merge base*.  The merge base is defined by the *commit graph*, formed by the inter-connections from one commit to another.  While we won't go into all the details, you can think of this as *the best **shared** commit*, i.e., the best commit that's on *both* branches.  Starting from `J`—as found by name `feature1`—we work backwards; and starting from `H`, as found by `master`, we also work backwards.  When some commit is on *both* branches, that's a *shared* commit.  The newest such commit—with *newest* not being properly defined here, but in most cases it's obvious—is usually the *best* commit.<sup>2</sup>

In this case, the merge base is clearly commit `H` itself.

---

<sup>1</sup>The merge I'll do here is the kind you would get on GitHub, using its "merge pull request" button.  From the Git command line, you get more options.  The `--no-ff` option forces command-line Git to make a real merge, instead of using its short-cut "fast forward not-really-a-merge" option.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, what Git is doing is finding the Lowest Common Ancestor (LCA) in a directed graph.  In a *tree*, there is always one well-defined LCA, but Git's commit graph is not necessarily a single tree: it's just a Directed Acyclic Graph or DAG.  Two commits may have no LCA, or may have more than one LCA, and merge does different things for these cases.

---

#### Merging, part 2

Having found the merge base, Git now runs *two* of its *compare two commits and see what changed* operations.  Comparison #1 compares the merge base to the `--ours` commit, i.e., to `HEAD`.  So Git will do:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-H>   # what we changed on master
```

Obviously, commit `H` is the same as commit `H`.  Nothing at all changed!

Then, Git does a second diff, to see what "they" (we) changed on the other side:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what they changed on feature1
```

What merge does, then, is to *combine* these two sets of changes.  Where we changed some file, and they didn't, Git takes our change.  Where they changed some file, and we didn't, Git takes their change.  **These combined changes get applied to the merge-base snapshot.**  That way, we keep all our work and add their work—but wherever we and they made *different* changes to some file or files, Git will show a *merge conflict*.

In this case, the `--ours` diff is completely empty: we didn't change anything.  So whatever "they"—really, we on `feature1`—did, Git takes those changes.  That includes adding a new file `test1`.  This combining goes well, so Git makes the new merge commit on its own.

The *first parent* of the new merge commit is our current commit, `H`, on `master`.  The second parent of the new merge commit is their commit `J`, on `feature1`.  We can draw that—the drawing here doesn't show first vs second commit properly, but we can just remember it if we need to, or ask Git about both parents to see which one is first, or whatever.

The result looks like this:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1
         /    \
...--G--H------M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- feature2
```

Note how no *other* branch name moved: we're still on `master`, and it has moved to point to `M`, and `feature1` still names commit `J` and `feature2` still names commit `L`.

#### The conflicting merge

If we now run another `git merge`—this time with `feature2`—Git will once again locate three commits:

- The ours and theirs commits are commits `M` and `L`, of course.
- The merge base is the best *shared* commit.

Look at the diagram.  Which commits are on both `master` *and* `feature2`?  Commits `G-H-I-J-M` are all on `master`—`H` in *two* ways, directly from the first parent of `M`, and indirectly by going from `J` to `I` to `H` through the second parent of `M`—and hence `G` is there in two ways, and so on, but all we really care about is that `H` and `G` are there.

Meanwhile, `feature2` ends at `L`, goes back to `K`, then goes back to `H`.  So commits `H` and `G` are both shared.  Commit `H` is the *best* one, though.  Once again, then, the merge base is commit `H`.

Git will once again run two `git diff`s, both with `--find-renames` (to check for renamed files) and both from `H` to the two branch tips.  So Git is going to compare the snapshot in `H` against the one in `M`, to see what we changed.

What *did* we change, from `H` to `M`?  Well, in `M`, we added all the changes we got by comparing `H` vs `J`.  So any files we *changed* in `feature1` are changed in `M`.  But we also added a new file, `test1`, in either `I` or `J`, so this change-set says *add all-new file `test1`*.

When we compare `H` vs `L`, that, too, says *add an all-new file `test1`*.  So *both changesets say to add a new file*.

**Git calls this kind of conflict an *add/add conflict*.**  In the work-tree, Git just leaves you with the entire contents of both files as your conflict.  You must resolve this conflict in some way.  How you go about it is up to you.  Whatever you choose to put in file `test1`, you can now run:

```
git add test1
```

and Git will assume that whatever is in the file `test1` is the *correct* resolution for that conflict.

**Be sure to edit the file!  If you don't, it just has the conflict markers in it, and Git thinks that's the *right answer!*  It probably isn't.**

Once you have resolved all conflicts, and are sure that the merge result is correct—you've done any testing you need to do, for instance—you can safely finish the merge by running either:

```
git merge --continue
```

or:

```
git commit
```

(The `git merge --continue` just makes sure you're still finishing the merge, then runs `git commit` for you, so they wind up doing the same thing—unless you already finished, or terminated, the merge, that is.)

Git will now make *another* merge commit; we'll call it commit `N`, and draw it like this:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1
         /    \
...--G--H------M--N   <-- master (HEAD)
         \       /
          K-----L   <-- feature2
```

The first parent of `N` is `M`, and the second parent of `N` is `L`.  There are now *three* ways to get from `N` to `H`, and *all* commits in the diagram are on `master`.

It's now safe to delete the names `feature1` and `feature2` because Git can find those commits—including `J` and `L`—by going backwards from commit `N`.  You don't *have* to delete the names, if you want to retain the ability to find commits `J` and `L` directly and quickly, but they're no longer *necessary*, like they were before the merge operations.