# Git Pull request conflicts for the same file created by different users

Tags: git, pull-request, merge-conflict-resolution

What will happen if both files(with the same names) in separate branches are created by different users?

i.e.
I currently have a file named `test1` in a branch named `branch1` created from master and another user has created the file with the same named `test1` in a branch named `branch2` also created from master.

> user1 creates -> file1 in -> branch 1

> user2 creates -> file1 in -> branch 2

What's gonna happen to the code written in both files if I merge the 2 branches in master?
Will it allow to merge the PR just like above?
or the same `file1` will have 2 different references in repo?

*Note: I have referred following **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532257/merging-2-files-with-the-same-name-in-2-different-branches-in-git/62790124#62790124)** already.*

Comment: The link answers your question. It will cause a merge conflict which you will need to resolve. [Merging 2 files with the same name in 2 different branches in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532257/merging-2-files-with-the-same-name-in-2-different-branches-in-git)

Comment: @NickMcCurdy this is not what I am asking about.
I have already shared the same link in the question only stating that I have referred this link!

Answer (score 1):

The linked question is about merging.  Your question is about a pull request.  These are strongly related, but not the same thing.

The real problem here is that "pull request" is not well-defined:

- If you mean a PR on GitHub or Bitbucket or some similar service provider, there's one possible answer: there will be a merge conflict that, in general, requires using an external agent like Git itself—and not the browser-oriented fixers that the service provider gives you—to resolve the conflict.  That is, one of the PRs may well go in easily, after which the other one will not.
- If you mean email generated by `git request-pull`, that simply produces an email message that you can then send to someone else who, presumably, has a full command-line Git.  When they merge one of the two requests, it will probably go in easily as above; when they attempt to merge the other, *they* will get the merge conflict, and it's up to *them* to decide what to do about this.

I've added a long answer to the other question, though, as the underlying issue is not specifically about *branches* per se, but rather about *commits*, and how merge works based on commits.

Comment: your first point above seems like an answer then. Thanks.